# How to get javascript caller source line number in SpiderMonkey JSNative callback?

Tags: javascript, debugging, spidermonkey

I want to implement a C++ function working like console.log. I need to know javascript caller's source line position in C++. I search MDN JSAPI/JS Debugger API documents but no result.

A concept usage in javascript.

```
console.log("blahblahblah");
```

And expected logic in C++.

```
JSBool consoleLog(JSContext *cx, unsigned argc, jsval *vp) {
    // expect to get caller info including filename, lineno.

    // write "blahblahblah" and caller info in my log system.

    return JS_TRUE;
}
```

==============

**UPDATE**

I finally find a way to get filename and lineno. Error handling code is omitted.

```
#include "jsdbgapi.h"

JSBool consoleLog(JSContext *cx, unsigned argc, jsval *vp) {
    JSScript *script;
    unsigned int lineno;
    JS_DescribeScriptedCaller(cx, &script, &lineno);
    const char *filename = JS_GetScriptFilename(cx, script);

    // use filename and lineno to write log...

    return JS_TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally you have to use the *currently active function frame* on the JS stack, accessible through `cx` -- that would tell you about the script and currently executing bytecode. Though I can't remember the exact API off the top of my head, there's some function that will produce lineno from that data (don't be avoid to forgo the docs and start reading `jscntxt.h` and friends, seeing as how the docs can be outdated -- they're not auto-generated).

There's also a caveat in that JSNatives conceptually execute in their caller's stack frame, so calling consoleLog from another JSNative it won't say something like `<native code>`. It'll only effectively do what you want when invoked from a JS-code caller.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I finally use `JS_DescribeScriptedCaller` and `JS_GetScriptFilename` to get script filename and lineno successfully.